# Which is more preferable: We have deemed it x or we deem it x?

Tags: grammar, tenses

Consider these examples:

1. We have deemed it proper to let you handle this matter.
2. We deem it proper to let you handle the matter.

Which one is more preferable?

Comment: Most of the time both work, although one can imagine circumstances where you could use only (1) or only (2). The difference between present perfect and present tense doesn't change because the verb is *deem*.

Comment: 'Preferable' is preferable to 'more preferable'.

Comment: They both sound very pompous.  The second sounds exceptionally pompous because it echoes the "majestic plural" (aka "the royal *we*") used by British Monarchs, who apparently think of themselves as an odd mix of an individual and an avatar representing an entire nation.   If you're trying to maximise pomposity, go with 2.

Answer (score 1):

The Present Perfect tense signifies an action that began in the past but whose effect continues into the present. [OWL](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/601/01/).

Sentence 1 implies that the deeming occurred in the past but its effect continues into the present.

Sentence 2 implies that the deeming occurred in the present (now).

Which is preferable depends on which sense you wish to communicate.